# Как выполнить поиск по истории Qiwi?

Tags: python, requests, qiwi

```
def check_buy(m):
    s = requests.Session()
    parameters = {
        'operation': 'IN',
        'rows': '10'
    }
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    s.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + config.api_access_token
    r = s.get('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v2/persons/' + config.my_number + '/payments',
              params=parameters)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    for i in range(0, 10):
        comment = data['data'][i]['comment']
        amount = str(data['data'][i]['sum']['amount'])
        data_buy = data['data'][i]['date'][:10]
```

Рофл в том, что переменная принимает последнее значение. 
Пример что выводит в логи и какое значение переменной ниже:

```
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-10-01'
'2019-09-30'
'2019-09-30'
'2019-09-29'
'2019-09-29'
'2019-09-29'
'2019-09-29'
'2019-09-29'
'2019-09-29'
'2019-09-29'
```

Значение переменной - '2019-09-29'.
Как сделать переменную списком этих объектов?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Какая переменная? Какое значение? Кто выводит? В каких логах? В показанном вами коде нет ни единого принта. Какой конкретно результат вы ожидаете? Список каких объектов?

Comment: Что такое "Рофл"? Что знатит "сделать переменную скиском этих объектов"?

Answer (score 0):

Значение переменной - '2019-09-29'. Это значение data_buy?
Я не очень понял условие. Вижу, что данные достаются в цикле и каждый раз записываются в одни и те же переменные. Если заменить переменные на списки, то они будут хранить все нужные данные

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
comment = list()
amount = list()
data_buy = list()
for i in range(0, 10):
    comment.append(data['data'][i]['comment'])
    amount.append(str(data['data'][i]['sum']['amount']))
    data_buy.append(data['data'][i]['date'][:10])
```

А можно хранить в словаре например, где ключом будет например comment (если он уникален) или ввести абстрактный id. А значениями остальные параметры.

Comment: Очень большое спасибо за последний ответ!